# How to use data from .csv file for Ultimate thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have a use case where 10000 users are hitting the API sequentially. 
first 1000 users/sec are hitting an API then they hold for 10-15 seconds and again another 2000 users are going to access the api.

Issue is i have an api `<path>/user_id/${userId}` and i have 10000 user ids stored in a .csv file 
how fetch the file for every 1000 users at first set and 2000 users in the next?
I have added CSV Data set Config and i have the .csv file path

Below screenshot is my .csv set config.
[image]
Beanshell error

[image]

GetUserID API

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ashu

To pick first 1000 userIds for first 1000 threads and and next 2000 userids for next 2000 threads and so on follow this steps

Create a csv file with only userIds(Do not mention the column name in csv).

To the JMeter test plan add a simple thread group and bean shell sampler to the thread group.

Add the following code to the beanshell sampler [image: Code]

above code will add UserIds to JMeter properties.
now to pick userIds use

```
${__P(user_id_${__longSum(${__threadNum},-1,)})}
```

I have created a sample test plan to pick only first 10 values from csv for the first minute and pick next 10 for the next minute you can see the screenshot here

[image: Ultimate Thread Group]
[image: Results Tree]

I would recommend run the tests in cloud.
Please follow this link to  [know more](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2018/01/load-test-with-unique-users/)

Comment: i am getting below error
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.LineNumberReader; import java.io.File; import java.io.FileReader; . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: string not found in namespace

Comment: I have an API when the userID is passed to the api it return the result. userId is taken from the .csv file. also the above code is not incrementing to the next row userid.

Comment: Ashu,

The error is because of string namespace,
S should be capital in String, Please make this change and see

Comment: Rohit i have opened new question as i am facing a different issue altogether now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447676/how-to-send-values-bean-shell-sampler-to-a-rest-api-in-jmeter/50448973?noredirect=1#comment87916713_50448973