# How to send values bean shell sampler to a rest api in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

To begin with i am new to Jmeter. I have a scenario where i have set of 20000 usersemployeeid in a .csv file and i have a rest api path/getempid/${empid}. Scenario is 1000 users hit the api at a time and for every 20-25 seconds they hold. and after 20 25 seconds another set of users say 3000 users hit the api. I have a CSV data set config, bean shell sampler and Ultimate thread group.

Please find the below attachments
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When i run the test the result in view results tree looks like

BeanshellSampler
111
111
111
222
111
222
111
333
333
333
222
111

Instead

111
222
333
444
555

etc so on

Also instead of running for one time. There is an entry of 500.

My scenario is 20 users in .csv file 1st 10 users should hit the api and then the second set of 10 users

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of your ultimate thread group settings. Put start thread group count as 10 and rest everything 0 to get 111 222 333.

See the output with everything 0 except for "start thread count":-

[image]

If you want output to be multiple times then the result will be same as you are getting now.

I hope this help.

Comment: sunny_teo But for the scenario i have to add another set of threads to check the load. The Above solution do not work.

Comment: @Ashu123 The beanshell is running only once to read the file and put everthing in properties. Then, it is your ultimate thread group that is controlling how many number of thread for how long..basically your performance scenario. Still, I dont understand why you need all in sequence while your are using multiple threads. I am just trying my best to understand your scenario. Pardon me if I miss something. If you want different number of threads with different data sets...then simple solution is to have multiple thread grps with multiple data sets  and run sequentially.

Comment: My scenario is i have 20000 user employee id and a rest api. when u pass a single employee id to the rest api the api gives me a response with 200 ok code. Now i want to check, 1000 employee id is passed to the api / second and check the behavior and after 10-15 seconds i want to pass another 5000 employee id to check how my api perform, and again after 10-15 seconds i want to pass anothoer 6000 employee id's and so on. I suppose Ultimate thread group is the best solution for this. And i have 20000 employee id's in a .csv file. where i want to fetch every single first 1000 employee id.

Comment: @Ashu124 Yes,,for the scenario like this it is perfect. But, then you can have like 10000 users data in the csv and let them pick the user id in sequence and put recycle on. I hope your scenario is to increase the hits on the server like from 1000 to 5000 to 20000 and should not depend on user IDs as it should be fine if it is repeating after a certain pause or this is also not the case.I think you already have what you are looking for...your original scenario is just fine until you  are looking to have unique user hits.

Comment: my api response only if i pass an userid or else it gives me 404 status error

Comment: @Ashu123 I am not saying not to use them as it is required. But, even if they are repeated then would it be a problem for your load test scenario.